# Spring Integration - copy message headers to JMS Message

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I am trying to send reply Q details in the JMS Header when using Outbound Gateway in spring integration. I learnt that enhances made in JIRA #INT-97 copies the spring message headers to JMS headers before sending it to the JMS destination.

Before sending the message to the outbound gateway, set the message header as below.
**message.getHeader().setAttribute(JmsTargetAdapter.JMS_REPLY_TO, myReplyDestination);**

But I am not able to find the JmsTargetAdapter class in any of the SI jars.

Can anybody help me out with the jar that has this class?

Also, Is my below understanding correct?

1. Enrich your message header with the JMSReplyTo attribute which has an MQQueue object (I'm sending messages to MQ)
2. Post the message using outbound gateway (by default, the JMS Headers will be appended with the SI headers)

EDIT:

I have source and destination systems where source sends request to a MQ broker eg: MQBroker 1 and destination sends back the reply to MQBroker 2. Both the brokers are interconnected through middleware layer.

I need to pass the reply Q and Q Manager details in the request header for the destination to put back the reply. But the reply Q details are residing in Broker 2 whereas the outbound gateway configs will have the Broker 1 configuration.

How to achieve this with Outbound gateway? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very old issue from a very, very, old pre-release of the framework.

See [the current documentation about how to use the outbound gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-outbound-gateway).

You don't need to set up the headers that way; configure one of the `reply-destination*` attributes on the gateway.

**EDIT**

In reply to your comment:

The gateway cannot talk to two different brokers. You would have to use outbound and inbound channel adapters for that, and do your own reply correlation.

To do that, you could use a header enricher to set the `jms_replyTo` header...

```
<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header name="jms_replyTo" ref="someReplyDestination" />
    <int:header name="jms_correlationId" expression="headers['id'].toString()" />
</int:header-enricher>
```

...where `someReplyDestinaion` is a `<bean/>` representing your vendor's queue object. The second header will set the `JMSCorrelationId`. (Or you can use your own correlation mechanism).

The `JMSCorrelationID` in the reply will be in header `jms_correlationId`.

As long as the server echoes back the same correlation id, you will be able to match the reply with the request; either in your own code, or with an aggregator.

Comment: I have configured a reply-destination attribute that resides in the same MQ hub but the system who sends out the reply should post the  it to a diff MQ hub. the middleware is connected between the two MQ hubs. Not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Not sure how to send the reply Q and Q manager details to the destination system

Comment: If suppose I'm using outbound gateway, won't i be able to populate the JMS headers in the SI message that the source system is posting? The destination system needs the reply Q details that resides in their MQ hub as part of the JMS header only. the middleware is interconnected. so the req and res destinations in the gateway config resides in the same broker

Comment: Then you have nothing to do; the gateway will set the reply destination in the `JMSReplyTo` header for you. It should "just work". You need to show your complete configuration and properly describe what's not working. Do not put configuration in a comment; edit the question instead.

Comment: If the gateway populates the JMSReplyTo from the config that I give, the destination system will not be able to put the reply. The reply-destination that I give in the outbound gateway is diff and the JMSReplyTo attribute sent in JMS headers should be diff. Can this be achieved?

Comment: You are still not being very clear with your question; as I pointed out in my original answer, there are several options to specify the reply destination; one is `reply-destination-expression`. This expression must resolve to a `Destination` or the name of a destination, in which case, the destination resolver will resolve the name to a `Destination`. If you put the destination in a header, you can use `reply-destination-expression="headers['replyDest']"`. If you still don't understand, please edit your question with configuration and __exactly__ what you are trying to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94737/discussion-between-swathy-and-gary-russell).